# Accounting for autocorrelation of a time series in a GAMM

Tags: r, moving-average, gam, autoregressive-models

I am investigating how environmental/oceanographic factors affect fisheries landings. I have the following GAMM in R, using the `gam` function:

```
GAMM1 <- gam(log(weight.landed + 1) ~ s(day.in.series) + s(month) + s(wind.speed) + s(wind.direction,bs="cc") + s(SST) + s(Chl.a) + s(fisherID,bs="re") + offset(log(effort)), data=mydata)
```

`fisherID` is a variable identifying individual fishermen, which is the random part of the GAMM.
`effort` is used as an offset, to standardise the weight of catch to the amount of fishing gear used.
`day.in.series` is the ordered days in the time series (1 - 6000) and `month` is calendar month to show seasonal effects.
All other variables are various environmental data.

The ACF:
[image: ACF] and partial ACF:
[image: partial ACF] plots indicate there is autocorrelation in the data. In the ACF plot, there are significant lags until about lag 30, and I'm not entirely sure what the partial ACF plot is telling me.

From what I have researched, I need to incorporate corARMA into my model. Can that be done using the `gam` function, or does `gamm` need to be used instead? I am also unsure if random variables (`fisherID`) and offsets affect this in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to the argument "correlation = corARMA(form=...,p = , q = )" in the function gamm